# required icon for label UI component

Tags: html, knockout.js, jet, oracle-jet

I have a dynamic label component in html ;  where its  'required' value is based on API response true/false . Is it possible to set ojComponent{  required: true }property for this label

*Date

From ----

To ----

```
  <label data-bind="text: fldUiLabel, css:{'required': $data.mandatoryFldInd}">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to ["required"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp), then it's an attribute and not a css class. You would apply it with the ["attr"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding.

```
<label data-bind="text: fldUiLabel, attr:{'required': $data.mandatoryFldInd}">
```